# Counting how many records are true

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'd like to do a query like this:

`select count(c.id) as count, sum(c.boolProperty) as sum from c`

with data like this:

`{ "id":"1","boolProperty":true}
{ "id":"2","boolProperty":false}`

to return

`{ "count": 2, "sum": 1 }`

I suspect I will need to do two queries, but wanted to check

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this since your boolproperty is a boolean so it cannot do a aggregation over it.

Instead you can use where clause , but in this case it will be applied to count as well

```
SELECT COUNT(C.id) as count,  COUNT(C.id) as sum  FROM C where C.boolProperty = true
```